# rails split string with custom length

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

I'm using Rails and MongoMapper as my working platform.

I want to generate a custom key with the help of month and year. The possible format would be `YYYYMM####`,

- `YYYY` is current YEAR which I can get as `Date.today.strftime("%Y")`
- `MM` is current Month Which I can get as `Date.tody.strftime("%m")`

  - After that `###` is incremented integer value

I get the last job with the code

```
jobForLastnum = Job.last(:order => :_id.desc)
lastJobNum = jobForLastnum.job_number
```

Now my question is I received the `job_number` as '201305100'

I want to split it with custom length like, `['2013','05','100']`

I know how to split a string in ruby and I successfully did that but i got result as individual character like

```
['2','0','1','3','0','5','1','0','0']
```

With the help of this I could retrieve the year:

```
lastJobNum.to_s[0,4]
```

With the help of this I got the month:

```
lastJobNum.to_s[4,2]
```

But after that there is custom length string. How can I get all the data in a single array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use ranges:

```
c = "2013121003"
[c[0..3], c[4..5], c[6..-1]]
```

You can also use [`String#unpack`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-unpack):

```
"20131210034".unpack("A4A2A*")
```

Or with regexp as suggested by tessi, using [`String#scan`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-scan):

```
c = "2013121003"
c.scan(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d+)/)
```

In all cases, this will return an array with the year, month, and job id as strings.

Answer (score 1):

A regexp can help you here.

```
jobNumber = 201305100
year, month, job_id = jobNumber.to_s.match(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d*)/)[1..3]
```

First, we convert the jobNumber to a String. Then we throw a regexp at it. The regexp has three capture groups (`(\d{4})` four numbers for the year, `(\d{2})` two numbers for the month, `(\d*)` any remaining number for the job_id).

The `job_number.to_s.match(...)` returns a `MatchData` object, which we can access by its first three capture groups with `[1..3]` ([see the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/MatchData.html)).

Finally, we assign the resulting Array to our variables `year`, `month`, and `job_id`.

```
year
#=> 2013
month
#=> 05
job_id
 #=> 100
```